# How to get the locally formatted price out of these web pages

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

Microsoft has web pages showing the local prices for Windows in over 200 countries. For each country, there are separate web pages for Windows Pro, Windows Home, and Windows Workstation.

I'm trying to get the locally-formatted prices including currency symbol for each of the web pages. For many of them this works:

```
Const WEB_PRICE_HTML_CLASS_NAME_TYPE_1 As String = "pi-price-text"

Function GETWEBPRICE(url_web_price As String) As String
    Dim oXMLHTTP As Object
    Dim oHtmlDoc As Object
    Dim collTopics As Object
    
    Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set oHtmlDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
   
    oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", url_web_price, False: DoEvents
    oXMLHTTP.send: DoEvents
    
    oHtmlDoc.body.innerHTML = oXMLHTTP.responseText: DoEvents

    Set collTopics = oHtmlDoc.getElementsByClassName(WEB_PRICE_HTML_CLASS_NAME_TYPE_1): DoEvents
    GETWEBPRICE = collTopics(0).textContent
End Function
```

An example web page for which that works is this one:
https://www.microsoft.com/uk-ua/d/windows-10-pro/df77x4d43rkt

But some of them have a different html structure, and **that doesn't work**, such as this one:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/d/windows-10-pro/df77x4d43rkt

How do I get the locally-formatted prices from the web pages with that html structure?

Comment: use a css selector list with OR syntax inside querySelector() though this would mean using MSHTML.HTMLDocument. Otherwise, you would need to use a .Length = 0 test perhaps with Select case true and then each case be the various paths to html element desired and test of length. Alternatively, use regex to extract from JS objects within each page response.text and use alternation (|) or possibly a single regex to match across different cases (less likely).

Answer (score 0):

This uses a more general class, but does work for the AU site:

```
Const WEB_PRICE_HTML_CLASS_NAME_TYPE_1 As String = "font-weight-semibold"

Function GETWEBPRICE(url_web_price As String) As String
    Dim oXMLHTTP As Object
    Dim oHtmlDoc As Object
    Dim collTopics As Object
    
    Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set oHtmlDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
   
    oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", url_web_price, False: DoEvents
    oXMLHTTP.send: DoEvents
    
    oHtmlDoc.body.innerHTML = oXMLHTTP.responseText: DoEvents

    Set collTopics = oHtmlDoc.getElementsByClassName(WEB_PRICE_HTML_CLASS_NAME_TYPE_1): DoEvents
    GETWEBPRICE = collTopics(0).innerText
End Function
```

Screenshot illustrating results for both URL:-
[image: Screenshot illustrating results of suggested code]

Comment: Thanks, but that does not work for the AU site.

Comment: @GregLovern that's odd - I've added a screenshot to illustrate that the code still works (even for the non-AU site)